# Why does creating a linked list in my code create a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to do an exercise on C. There are two arrays, `count` and `list`. `count` is an array of ints initially filled with 0, while `list` is an array of queues. My code is supposed to take pairs of numbers separated by a space eg. "1 2". For every pair of numbers, I must add 1 to the `2nd number-1` position in the `count` array, and then put a node containing the 2nd number in the head of the queue in the `1st number-1` position of the `list` array. My code is down below, and it results to a segmentation error after receiving the first pair of numbers. Removing lines 24-30 removes the error, but I don't understand what causes this error. Can anyone point out why it's doing a segmentation error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
  int succ;
  Node *next;
};

void set_initial_array(int count[], int n, Node *list[]);
void handle_input(char string[], int count[], Node *list[]);

void set_initial_array(int count[], int n, Node *list[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    count[i] = 0;
    list[i] = NULL;
  }
}

void handle_input(char string[], int count[], Node *list[]) {
  int j = atoi(&string[0]), k = atoi(&string[2]);
  count[k - 1]++;
  if (list[j - 1] != NULL) { // Removing line 24-30 removes error
    Node head = {k, list[j - 1]};
    list[j - 1] = &head;
  } else {
    Node head = {k, NULL};
    list[j - 1] = &head;
  }
}

int main() {
  char string[4];
  int count[15];
  Node *list[15];
  set_initial_array(count, n, list); //fill count with 0 and list with NULL
  while (fgets(string, 4, stdin) != NULL && strcmp(string, "0 0") != 0) {
    handle_input(string, count, list);
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this even compile, there is no variable `n` in `main`?

Comment: Non-static local variables will be invalidated on returning from the functions in which they are declared and storing pointers to them to variables that survive after returnig is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
Node head = {k, list[j - 1]};
list[j - 1] = &head;
```

`head` is a local variable, which will go of scope (or in simple terms: it will be destroyed) as soon as the `handle_input` function returns.

In this line `list[j - 1] = &head;` you store the address of that local variable in the list array which points actually to an array provided in `main`.

You need to handle this differently by allocating memory:

```
Node *head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
head->succ = k;
head->next = list[j - 1]
list[j - 1] = head;
```

There may be other problems though, I didn't check.

Don't forget to free the allocated memory at some point in `main`.